# Using jquery plugins for multiple element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am still new with jquery plugins. I have just created a plugin which end up confuse me.
here is the quick similar code I have:

```
(function(a) {
var writting = {
   container : "",
   textarea : "",

   init : function(el) {
      this.container = a(el);
      this.textarea = a("> textarea.wtxt", this.container);
   },

   manageLink : {
      initialise : function() {
         a("> .link_container > .toggleLink", writting.container).click(function() {
            writting.manageLink.removePreviousLink();
            a(this).toggleClass("hide");
         });
      },

      removePreviousLink : function() {
         // implementation
      },

      // all other functions
   }
}

a.fn.writting = function() {
   writting.init(this);
}
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    $("#writting_box1").writting();
    $("#writting_box2").writting();
});
```

basically there are going to be a lot of writting box, above code wont do anything to the #writting_box1, it always take effect on the writting_box2 / whatever writting box that declared last.

Thank you.

Comment: You should be using `return this.each` so it can iterate over the elements you want to pass in. You can also pass `$('[id^=writing_box]').each(function(){ $(this).writing(); });` to instantiate it on all elements that `begin with the id writing_box`. This should save you some time in the future. You could also make the plugin more robust to add an option to `check for multiple elements` and conditionalize the each function. either way, `return this.each`.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have tried using the return this.each on the init. however it still doing exactly the same like before. always the last box being declare is executed.

is it because of in the manageLink.initialise(), I have the function "writting.manageLink.removePreviousLink();" that cause it? global variable? is there any better way to do this? in the plugins that I wrote, I need to access the other functions inside the jquery function.